# Can't get regexes to work in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am using asp.net MVC2 and I am attepmting to add regexes to do some forms for some validation...
That being said, none of them are working at all.
First thing I did was attempt to do a simple .blur function call.  That didn't work at all...

```
$('#DischargeDateTimeMask').blur(function () {            
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var dateReg = /^(1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)? (am|pm)$/;
        if (!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
            //$(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-4">Incorrect time format fool!: HH:mm am|pm</span>');
        alert(dateReg.test(input));
        }
    });​
```

I just wanted to test to see if my regex was catching anything, and apparently it is throwing some kind of error.  So I said screw that and I decide to try and add an extra method to the Jquery Validator... My failure is document below...

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "time",
        function(value, element){
            /^(1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)? (am|pm)$/.test(value);
        },
        "The time format is invalid"
    );
$("#temp1").validate({
        rules: {
DischargeDateTimeMask: {
                time: true,
                required: false
            }
        },
        messages: {
        }
    });
});
```

Ignore some of the rest of the code... I have other validation rules in there that do work (when I get rid of this code) but are unrelated.  What on earth am I doing wrong?  It seems as though everything is on the up and up here?  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: I don't know the jQuery validator plugin, but I guess you should actually `return` the `.test` result. Something like `return /^...` may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're going to want to have your method check whether required is set or not, otherwise it will always check your regex, even when `required: false` is also set.  So the first line of your new method should be this:

```
if (this.optional(element)){ return true;}
```

And as other people pointed out, you need to return the result.  I also think your regular expression is a bit off with the spaces part, I would just make it `\s?` unless I'm missing something.

So you're total function would look like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "time",
    function(value, element){
        if (this.optional(element)){ return true;}

        return /^(1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)? (am|pm)$/.test(value);
    },
    "The time format is invalid"
);
```

Here it is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/w7EAV/

Comment: Great answer.  I eventually came to this conclusion myself.  Since you stated it so much better than I, I will give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently...

```
$('#DischargeDateTimeMask').blur(function () {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var dateReg = /^(1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)? (am|pm)+$/;
        if (!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-4">Incorrect time format fool!: HH:mm am|pm</span>');
        }
        //alert(dateReg.test(inputVal));
    });
```

This works but what I had before does not.  It looks exactly like what I had before but whatever.  But with that experience under my belt I decided to try and get the validation working... Apparently what I had worked before, I just had an error somewhere else in my code.  Thanks for the help guys.